# ROBOT FRAMEWORK - Create session with AUTH and Headers - Getting TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: robotframework

How ti create session with AUTH and Headers using Robot framework?

I tried the below code:

```
*** Variables ***
${user}    ='user1api'
${passwd}    ='password!'
&{headers}  Content-Type=application/json  Authorization=Basic ABCDEF==

*** Keywords ***
DO Status Get API   
    ${auth}=  Create List  user passwd
    Create Session  DOStatus  https://test.abc.com/api/status/7661/job  headers=${headers}  auth=${auth}
    ${resp}=  Get Request  DOStatus  /basic-auth/user/passwd
```

and ran into this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: This code can't give that error. The first line will throw the error "no keyword with name '=user1api' found". Please show a [mcve], and also tell us which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Thank Bryan. I passed user and passwd as ${user}    ='user1api' 
${passwd}    ='password', still i am facing same error. Create session line is throwing error.

Comment: We can only comment on what is in the question. Most  likely the problem is with how you are defining `${auth}`, If that line is in a `*** Variables ***` table, that may be the problem. We can't know because you aren't showing us actual code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Bryan, i am sorry. I have updated the code and ran it. now i am observing TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) at create session.

Comment: Now the title and the body don't match. You also need to state what library you're using.

Answer (score 3):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library           Collections
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
${user} =  user1api
${passwd} =  password!
&{headers}  Content-Type=application/json  Authorization=Basic ABCDEF==

*** Keywords ***
Get DO Status API   
${auth}=  Create List  ${user}  ${passwd}
Create Session  alias=DOStatus  url=https://test.abc.com/api/status/7661/job  headers=${headers}  auth=${auth}
${resp}=  Get Request  DOStatus  /
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.json()['transaction']['status']}  success
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using basic auth, you need to pass a tuple, assuming you are using the requests library.

If you are importing variables from a .yaml file, I think you could remove my Convert To Boolean and Evaluate keywords

The code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     requests

*** Variables ***
${user}=    "test_user"
${pass}=    "test_pw"
${url}=   https://special.domain/some/api/endpoint
&{headers}=   content-type=application/json   accept=application/json

*** Keywords ***
api check test
    ${false}=    Convert To Boolean    False
    ${user_pass}=   Evaluate   (${user}, ${pass},)
    ${resp}=    Get    ${url}    auth=${user_pass}   headers=${headers}  verify=${false}
    Log To Console    ${resp.status_code}
```

The result:

```
Api Validation :: API Validation                                  
==============================================================================
Test API                                                              
...<warning goes here>...
200
Test API                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Api Validation :: API Validation                                      | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason the OP's code didn't work as expected was because of the single missing space when setting the `auth` variable and consequently producing a Python requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth call of just `(self, 'username & password')` rather than `(self, 'user', 'password')`. The constructor signature expects `__init__(self, username, password)` . This can be fixed by simply adding a single space to the original code which instructs RobotFramework to consider the variables as 2 separate values in the list. See the difference between the assign of *auth_bad* and *auth_good* in the code below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library         RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
${user}    ='user1api'
${passwd}    ='password!'
&{headers}  Content-Type=application/json  Authorization=Basic ABCDEF==

*** Keywords ***
DO Status Get API
    ${auth_bad}=  Create List  user passwd
    Log To Console  A bad authentication variable: ${auth_bad}
    ${auth_good}=  Create List  user  passwd
    Log To Console  A good authentication variable: ${auth_good}
    Create Session  DOStatus  https://192.168.1.254/api/status/7661/job  headers=${headers}  auth=${auth_good}
    ${resp}=  Get Request  DOStatus  /basic-auth/user/passwd


*** Task ***
Basic Task
    DO Status Get API
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you and I solved it.
I remove the headers in Create session.
You can refer my source:

**Variables**

```
    ${jira_url}    https://example.com
    ${jira_user}    user1
    ${jira_password}    password1
```

**Test Cases**

```
    Get All Testcase Of SC Project    
        ${auth}=    Create Dictionary   ${jira_user}      ${jira_password}      
        Create session    alias=Get_Jira_Request        url=${jira_url}  auth=${auth}
        ${response}=    Get Request   Get_Jira_Request    /rest/atm/1.0/testcase/search?query=projectKey%20=%20%22SC%22
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I struggled for one day to figure it out.

Define:
&{dict}    accept=text/plain     Authorization=Basic
@{auth}    ${user}    ${pwd}

If we use Create List/ Create Dictionary, it does not work.
@{auth}    Create list    ${user}    ${pwd}

```
Create Session    em    url=${url}    verify=false    auth=${auth}
```

=========

```
*** Variables ***

${user}    user1api
${passwd}    password!
&{headers}    Content-Type=application/json    Authorization=Basic

*** Keywords ***
DO Status Get API   
    @{auth}    ${user}    ${passwd}
    Create Session    DOStatus    https://test.abc.com/api/status/7661/job  headers=${headers}  auth=${auth}
```

I hope this will solve the problem of create session